# Creating xml from JAXB when one value is retrieved using a factory method

Tags: jaxb

I have a UUID class where I get the uuid from a static factory method like 
UUIDGenerator.getInstance().getUuid();

I have another class which has these UUids as a list.

```
  class Artifact
    {
      Uuid uuid;
      setUuid(Uuid uuid)
      { 
        this.uuid = uuid;
      }

      Uuid getUuid()
      {
        return this.uuid;
       }
    }


Class ArtifactData
{
  private  List<Artifact> artifacts;
   //setter for list
  // getter for list

}
```

I want the xml to be created as

```
<ArtifactData>
<AssociatedArtifactList>
<ArtifactUuid>#some value<ArtifactUuid>
</AssociatedArtifactList>
</ArtifactData>
```

How do I create this xml out of Jaxb annotations. It complains on saying there isn't a public constructor for Uuid because it is constructed out of a factory method.

EDIT: The Uuid and Uuid generator cannot be modified. They are in a JAR. This is what I have tried so far

```
public class Artifact
{
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(ArtifactUuidAdapter.class)
    private Uuid uuid;


    public Uuid getUuid()
    {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(Uuid uuid)
    {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

}

@XmlRootElement
public class ArtifactData
{
    private List<Artifact> associatedArtifactList;
    public List<Artifact> getArtifacts()
    {
        return associatedArtifactList;
    }

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="associatedArtifactList")
    @XmlElement(name = "artifactUuid")
    public void setArtifacts(List<Artifact> artifacts)
    {
        this.associatedArtifactList = artifacts;
    }
}


public class ArtifactUuidAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Uuid, String>
{
    @Override
    public Uuid marshal(String uuid) throws Exception
    {
        return Uuid.getInstance(uuid);
    }

    @Override
    public String unmarshal(Uuid uuid) throws Exception
    {
        return uuid.getData();
    }
}
```

I still get an error called no arg default constructor is missing.

Comment: Maybe using @XmlJavaTypeAdapter annotation http://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlJavaTypeAdapter.html to convert it to a different type, String for instance, works (never tried this myself).

Comment: What would your XML look like if you had two instances of `Artifact` in the list?

Comment: It will be 2 ArtifactUuid elements

Answer (score 0):

The `@XmlType` annotation allows you to configure a factory class and method.  The factory class described in your questions doesn't quite meet the API requirements but you could easily create an adapter for it.

**UUIDGeneratorAdapter**

The class below would adapt your factory class to something that a JAXB (JSR-222) implementation could leverage.

```java
public class UUIDGeneratorAdapter {

    public static Uuid getUuid() {
        return UUIDGenerator.getInstance().getUuid();
    }

}
```

**Uuid**

Below is an example of how you configure the factory class through the `@XmlType` annotation.

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlType(factoryClass=UUIDGeneratorWrapper.class, factoryMethod="getUuid")
public class Uuid {

    // ...

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/jaxb-and-factory-methods.html

Comment: I don't have access to Uuid either .. it is packaged as a jar .. i only have access to ArtifactData